# How to detect if my app's vpn is connected in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, vpn

I want to know if my VPN is connected. If so, I wouldn't connect again and would shown a message "it's connected".

But if it's not my VPN, I should connect it.

Can I do this?

```
settings ["__SCOPED__": {
    en0 =     {
        ExceptionsList = (
            "*.local",
            "169.254/16"
        );
        FTPPassive = 1;
    };
}, "ExceptionsList": <__NSCFArray 0x282a58740>(
*.local,
169.254/16
)
, "FTPPassive": 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Check vpn connection with this code :

```swift
var isConnectedToVpn: Bool {
        if let settings = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()?.takeRetainedValue() as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
            let scopes = settings["__SCOPED__"] as? [String:Any] {
            for (key, _) in scopes {
                    if key.contains("tap") || key.contains("tun") || key.contains("ppp") || key.contains("ipsec") || key.contains("ipsec0") {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: I updated question. 
The same value is displayed, whether connected or not. so it always return false

Comment: try to add `key.contains("utun1") || key.contains("utun2")`

Comment: @Mac3n, `key` is always `en0`, tried both cases (with or without vpn)? Any Idea why?